# Magento 2 many to many product attribute

Tags: module, magento2.2, product-attribute

I want to create a module which is a product attribute and can have many items from my custom table, is there any guides or tutorials for something like this as I'm struggling to find anything but fully expect I'm searching for the wrong terminology.

The module would have it's own admin grid for adding and updating fields items these would then be displayed and orderable on each product admin page. You would be able to select multiple records and change the position of them.

Comment: Do you have any screenshots?

Comment: I don't have any screenshots as this is a module I intend to build.